# Apache HttpClient Components hangs?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to use Apache HttpClient Components in a JavaFX Application, but it hangs, and doesn't do anything at all when trying to execute.

I'm using IntelliJ and have only the httpclient-4.5.1.jar and httpcore-4.4.3.jar in the project's library.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am simply instantiating the Class that uses it with this:

```
HttpDownloadUtility httpDownloadUtility = new HttpDownloadUtility();
httpDownloadUtility.httpDownloadFile(param);
```

Here is the Class:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

public class HttpDownloadUtility {

    public void httpDownloadFile(Job job) {

        try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            response.close();

            System.out.println("Ran");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the real code/url, what is `Job` purpose? What do you mean by hang, did you try to get a dump (kill -3?)

Comment: I ran this on Java 8u72, OS X 10.9, httpclient 4.3.6, httpcore 4.3.3 and it ran fine (output "Ran").  I used an older version of httpclient for testing as that is what I had lying around.

Comment: I just want to test it so the URL can be anything that might work. With thread dump I get `"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING`, but "Ran" is not output, is that normal? Thanks

Comment: The behavior that you describe is not normal and is not the behavior that I experience when I test your code.

Comment: Hmm, well the method that instantiates the instance that uses HttpClient is being called by ScheduledService, on a Task, so maybe this would affect it.